# Python is busy with something else on my Windows computer

Tags: python, windows, performance-testing

The test is single-threaded and it calls 1000 times the function "calculate". This function sums all the integer from 0 to 10,000,000 in about 0.6 seconds. It returns the actual wall time it took to perform this calculation. The test keeps the track of the minimum time, the sum of times, and the sum of times squared. After 1000 calls the values of mean, standard deviation, and busy with something else are calculated and printed.

Busy with something else is: sum_time - minimum_time * number_of_loops

The value of busy with something on MacOS, Linux/Ubuntu, and iPad is from 0.493% to 4.050%. That is the expected toll from OS.

The results on Windows are constantly higher (best and worst from 10):

```
>python test.py 
Busy with something else 9.723% or 58.734 from 604.051 seconds 
min = 0.545 mean = 0.604 stdev = 0.133 

>python test.py 
Busy with something else 16.230% or 105.709 from 651.320 seconds 
min = 0.546 mean = 0.651 stdev = 0.194
```

My Windows computer info:

```
2.4 GHz Intel Core i5-6300U, Memory 4 GB 
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.379] 
Python version 3.7.2, Executing in 64bit
```

The test:

```python
import time
import sys


def calculate():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    result = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        result += i
    stop = time.perf_counter()
    return stop - start


number_of_loops = 1000

min_time = sys.maxsize
sum_time = 0.0
sum_time_square = 0.0
for _ in range(number_of_loops):
    t = calculate()
    min_time = min(min_time, t)
    sum_time += t
    sum_time_square += t ** 2

mean = sum_time / number_of_loops
stdev = ((sum_time_square + number_of_loops * mean**2 - 2.0 * mean * sum_time) /
         (number_of_loops - 1.0)) ** 0.5
busy_with_else = sum_time - min_time * number_of_loops
print('Busy with something else %.3f%% or %.3f from %.3f seconds' %
      (100.0 * busy_with_else / sum_time, busy_with_else, sum_time))
print('min = %.3f mean = %.3f stdev = %.3f' % (min_time, mean, stdev))
```

All tests executed on systems in the idle state before the test. The result of a similar C++ test on Windows is from 0.626% to 2.059%. So, it is not Windows to blame.

It is just my software/hardware or it can be reproduced and/or explained?

Comment: `sum_time - minimum_time * number_of_loops` is `(average_time - minimum_time) * number_of_loops`. The value shows the difference between fastest run and average run multiplied by number of runs for some reason. The value has very little meaning if any. It is not `busy with something else` time.

Comment: @Poolka that is why I use the first version: test time - the fastest run * number of runs. The fastest run or better should be achieved every time in a perfect OS. We don't know the better time but we do know the fastest run. Everything that is slower of this value is busy with something else not with the performing our calculation.

Comment: `busy with something else not with the performing our calculation` - like your web browser decided to go over some dark corners of your pc real quick? Anyway, windows is not real-time operating system so don't expect running time consistency of high accuracy.

Comment: @Poolka and I not trying to promote this as a new metric to testing: it just I called it when I was running the tests :-) It is not perfect by any means. For example, on Ubuntu a better overall run was penalized for achieving better faster run: (1) Busy with something else 4.050% or 22.094 from 545.455 seconds; min = 0.523 mean = 0.545 stdev = 0.025 vs (2) Busy with something else 2.902% or 16.211 from 558.525 seconds; min = 0.542 mean = 0.559 stdev = 0.018

Comment: @Poolka I know a little about real-time systems: programmed on them for about 11 years. This is why my test performs 1000 calls, not just one. The standard deviation values on Windows are 10 times greater and that is I expect to be addressed why.

Comment: If understand correctly you run the test on different machines with different operating systems and programming languages. Then you calculate some quantitative indicator based on the results. How many boundaries of applicability have been crossed along the way?

Comment: @Poolka could you just run my test on your Windows computer and see it yourself?  :-)